# How do you increase the size limit of file uploads in ReactJS?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, file-upload, axios

I have a reactJS frontend with a file upload component using NGINX to serve the frontend, that sends file data to my API and gets a response back. When I select a file larger than 1mb it never uploads the full data , only 1mb worth.

Example:

- I select a file of 1.6MB in size.

my file data state:

```
const [fileData, setFileData] = useState("");
```

This state returns a length of 1600202

I append the data for formData:

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", fileData);
formData.append("name", fileName);
```

The size of the formData is 1600210

I send the data to the API:

```
  await axios({
      url: `${baseUrl}/test`,
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        //"Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: globalState.sessionToken,
      },
      responseType: "arraybuffer",
      data: formData,
    })
```

The size on the network tab shows 1MB sent, along with the response size being 1048612 and the ArrayBuffer size being 1048612.

I know on the API side I have increased the upload limit to 5MB, but clearly something on the frontend is cutting data off at 1MB before it even reaches the server.

Is there a configuration I should be setting to allow larger file sizes?

Comment: Set appropriate [`client_max_body_size`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size) in the nginx config (default value is exactly 1 Mb).

Comment: client_max_body_size is set at 100M on frontend, and 5M on the API server. I'm wondering if that isn't the cause of this issue due to those settings.

Answer (score 1):

Could you provide some more info, does backend throw any errors, do you use some kind of library for parsing files (multer, formidable...)? Frontend size limits are only there if you manually check file size or if you set axios body max size. This is more of a comment but since I can't comment yet because of reputation I am posting it as an answer, sorry.

Comment: Sure! So on the API side it shows 1048576 as the size as soon as the endpoint is hit.
      ```console.log(file.length);
      console.log(Buffer.byteLength(file, "utf8"));
      console.log(await countBytes(file));```

all of these return the same size. this is before anything else is done with the data. 

I am using express on the API and NOT using any parsing files yet. I did add ```app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "10mb"}))``` with no change. It's just a giant string inside FormData when it sends it up right. but as soon as it hits the API it's somehow only 1MB.